# Using Kendo UI MVC treeview, how do i load all parents and children on initial load?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

How do I go about loading the treeview with all the parents and children.  Right now it loads only the Parents and then loads each child when you click.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("refModelTreeView")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .HighlightPath(true)
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Read(read => read
            .Action("LoadTreeView", "ReferenceModel").Data("addData")
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `expand` method as shown in the [TreeView API reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#methods-expand).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var treeview = $("#refModelTreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
    treeView.expand(".k-item"); 
});
```